# How to use reduceByKey to select records on particular columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe in which I want to remove duplicates based on a key, the catch is among the records sharing the same key, I need to select based on some columns and not just any record.

For example, my DF looks like:

```
+------+-------+-----+
|animal|country|color|
+------+-------+-----+
|   Cat|america|white|
|   dog|america|brown|
|   dog| canada|white|
|   dog| canada|black|
|   Cat| canada|black|
|  bear| canada|white|
+------+-------+-----+
```

Now I want to do remove duplicates based on column **animal**, and then have choose the ones which have **country** '*america*'.

My desired output should be:

```
+------+-------+-----+
|animal|country|color|
+------+-------+-----+
|   Cat|america|white|
|   dog|america|brown|
|  bear| canada|white|
+------+-------+-----+
```

Since there is no reduceBykey in Dataframe api, I convert this to a keyValue pair rdd and then do a reduceBykey I'm stuck in the function which will do this preference based selection amongst the duplicates.

I'll prefer the sample code in scala.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do what you with DataFrames in spark versions >= 1.4 using windows (at least I think that's what they're called).

However using RDDs

```
val input: RDD[(String, String, Row)] = ???
val keyedByAnimal: RDD[(String, (String, Row))] = 
    input.map{case (animal, country, other) => (animal, (country, other)) }
val result: RDD[(String, (String, Row))] = keyedByAnimal.reduceByKey{(x, y) =>
    if(x._1 == "america") x else y
}
```

The above gives you a single distinct value for each animal value. The choice of which value is non-deterministic. All that can be said about it is if there exists a value for the animal with "america" one of them will be chosen.

Regarding your comment:

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
val animalCol:String = ???
val countryCol: String = ???
val otherCols = df.columns.filter(c => c != animalCol && c!= countryCol)
val rdd: RDD[(String, String, Row)] = 
    df.select(animalCol, countryCol, otherCols:_ *).rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1), r)
```

The select reorders the columns so the getString methods pull out the expected values.
Honestly though, look into Window Aggregations. I don't know much about them as I don't use Dataframes or Spark beyond 1.3.

Comment: You are assuming too many things, The schema is not fixed but will be read from a file, The only thing know is key1(animal) and preference(country).
And we don't know which column number they'll exist in the schema, such hard codings won't work.

Comment: See edit. I assumed since you said that you converted your Dataframe into an RDD you'd have a known structure.

Comment: Appreciate the edit but the schema can have 10-15 fields instead of just 3 which i'll have to maintain, this won't be clean.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It can have a hundred. But you just select the 3 out that you want.

Comment: No, I want all the others also in the final output.

Comment: This is why you provide a minimum viable solution. There's enough scope there to solve any variation you want after my now final edit

Answer (score 0):

Provided that for all animal kind (dog, cat, ...) there is at least an entry for the country "america" and that you don't mind to loose duplicated matching animals within america, you can use `reduceByKey`:

```
val animals = sc.parallelize(("cat","america", "white")::("dog","america","brown")::("dog","canada","white")::("dog","canada","black")::("cat","canada","black")::("bear","canada","white")::Nil)

val animalsKV = animals.map { case (k, a, b) => k -> (a,b) }

animalsKV.reduceByKey {
    case (a @ ("america",_ ), _) =>  a
    case (_, b) => b
}
```

In case you might have animals with no entries in "america", the code above will take one of the duplicates: the last one. You can improve it by providing a result maintaining the duplicates in those cases. e.g:

```
animalsKV.combineByKey(
    Map(_), // First met entries keep wrapped within a map from their country to their color
    (m: Map[String, String], entry: (String, String)) => 
        if(entry._1 == "america") Map(entry) // If one animal in "america" is found, then it should be the answer value.
        else m + entry, //Otherwise, we keep track of the duplicates
    (a: Map[String, String], b: Map[String, String]) => //When combining maps...
        if(a contains "america") a // If one of them contains "america"
        else if(b contains "america") b //... then we keep that map
        else a ++ b // Otherwise, we accumulate the duplicates
)
```

That code can be modified to keep track of duplicated "american" animals too.

Comment: In your second piece of code keeping the duplicates won't work. Concatenating the maps only keeps 1 value for each unique key. eg.) Map(1 -> "A") ++ Map(1 -> "B") == Map(1 -> "B")


Also there's no need to use Maps as an Array would suffice and be more performant as you don't need to hash the values.

Comment: @ASpotySpot It does, try with `val animals = sc.parallelize(("cat","america", "white")::("dog","america","brown")::("dog","canada","white")::("dog","canada","black")::("cat","canada","black")::("bear","canada","white")::("bear", "spain", "brown")::Nil)`. You will get `Array((bear,Map(canada -> white, spain -> brown)), (dog,Map(america -> brown)), (cat,Map(america -> white)))` from collecting its results

Comment: Missing a case out. Try two values with the same animal and same country which is not america. ("cat", "canada", "white") :: ("cat", "canada", "black") Will return ("cat", "canada", "white") OR ("cat", "canada", "black") not both.

Comment: @ASpotySpot That is, you have an animal which isn't present in america but it is in "spain" and "canada", since the criteria for removing duplicates by country isn't fulfilled, all its cases will be kept. The problem with this is that the map shouldn't grow beyond each node limits but that is unlikely to happen given the amount of countries in the world. You can argue that duplicates by color won't be tracked but the snippet can be easily change to keep those duplicates too.

Comment: @ASpotySpot I was conscious about the duplicates by country & color but wanted to keep it simple in the suggestion of using the Spark operation `combineByKey` in order to provide results with different types to the `T` in `RDD[T]`

Comment: Fair enough. Good point about the Map not growing excessively large on each node too.

Comment: Can you modify the solution such that its not coupled tightly with the schema. I'm reading data from hive which will have many fields, I'll know the key column(animal) and preference column(country) and there will be other fields. Can you tell me something that'll work in that case.

Comment: @grv Then you should pass a different function to `reduceByKey`. You can build that function from your schema if you like. StackOverflow is about asking concrete questions, giving a ideas and not so much an on demand code generator. I can help you if you try something, still need some help and post some code...